# Build AliceVision with dependency to OpenCV

Tags: opencv, cmake, vcpkg

I'm trying to build [AliceVision](https://github.com/alicevision/AliceVision) via CMake for Visual Studio. Now when I set the variable `ALICEVISION_USE_OPENCV` I get the following error message when configuring via cmake-gui:

```
CMake Warning at C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:263 (_find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake

  but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be
  NOT FOUND.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/CMakeLists.txt:499 (find_package)


CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:515 (message):
  Failed to find OpenCV.
```

I have OpenCV installed through vcpkg. I cannot figure out what the problem is or how to solve it. I've tried to set the flag to `1` at some places manually but it doesn't help.

Comment: Scripts like `XXXConfig.cmake` usually set `XXX_FOUND` variable to FALSE when the package `XXX` is **incompatible** with the configuration you want.

Answer (score 1):

The log says:

> Could NOT find **OpenCV (missing: xfeatures2d)** (found version "4.1.1")

Which means you need the contrib packages of opencv.

```
.\vcpkg.exe install opencv[contrib] --recurse --triplet x64-windows
```

Comment: You mean that you've tried the same thing and got the same problem?

Comment: Yes, same problem. Then I updated my opencv by ```.\vcpkg.exe install opencv[opengl,jpeg,png,tiff,eigen,ffmpeg,ipp,dnn,ovis,sfm,contrib,webp, openexr,jasper] --triplet x64-windows --recurse```. It worked, but I think only `contrib` was necessary for this case.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that! I'll check if this solves my problem as well soon. Currently I'm not working on stuff related to AliceVision.